# XSL - Keep together 2 fo:blocks on a page

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

In XSLT I have `fo:region-body` with attribute `column-count="3"` and 2 `fo:blocks`. First of them have to be across all columns (title of the second `fo:block` with a horizontal line). The second one is a block of text divided between 3 columns.

```
<fo:block span="all">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//region[@name='BodyTitle']"/>
</fo:block>
<fo:block span="none">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="//region[@name='Body_3_Columns']"/>
</fo:block>
```

I would like to keep those blocks the same page but without positive result. Keep-together, Keep-with-next, etc. does not work on this case. I even tried to put those in `fo:block-container`, however both of them were displayed as either one or three columns depending on chosen span value (all / none).

Is there any way to resolve my problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AH Formatter, then you can make a three-column `fo:block-container` for the block of text:

```
<fo:block keep-with-next.within-page="always">...</fo:block>
<fo:block-container column-count="3" keep-together.within-page="always">...
```

If the document as a whole has three columns, then you can put `span="all"` on both the `fo:block` and the `fo:block-container` to get the correct width for the columns inside the `fo:block-container`.